# A young boy is granted wishes, one of which is a weird kind of shape shifting

Tags: story-identification, novel, young-adult

Looking for a YA novel.

I think the wish-giver is at the top of a dangerous mountain. Two boys make the journey but only one gets wishes.

The one thing I specifically remember is the boy wishes for the ability to change shape but instead of changing his own form, he kinda possesses other things while his original body disappears for the duration?

He also wishes for his friend to receive the same abilities as him, though the wish-granter hints that it will end poorly, some kind of betrayal, probably.

Comment: Take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and [edit] any more details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The book is called [*Dragon Fire*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/6543165.Dragon_Fire__Dragon_Fire___1_3_), part of a trilogy of the same name by Charles Aston!

> Extraordinary events transform the life of Sparrow after an encounter on the mountain with the wizard Puckel, who gives the boy three magical abilities: to fly; to understand the speech of beasts; and to take the shape of any creature or thing. Now Sparrow needs all the magical help he can get.

Comment: In about 46 hours, you'll be able to accept your answer, and we would like you to do so if at all possible.